# How to update with wpdb where ID more than 1

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Hello i'm new to wordpress. 
I want to know how to use `$wpdb` to update where `ID` in `('1' , '2')`.

Here is my code :

```
 $ids = 1,2,3,4,5;
 $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
          "
          UPDATE $wpdb->subcategory SET status = 0
          WHERE subcategory_id IN ( %s )
          ", 
          $ids
 ) );
```

I try this code but only updated first `id` (1).

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Please post the actual code you are running. The example you posted is not valid PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting `$ids` value.

```
$ids = "1,2,3,4,5";
```

Then use `sprintf()` function:

```
$wpdb->query( sprintf( "UPDATE %s SET status = 0
                                        WHERE subcategory_id IN ( %s )", 
                                        $wpdb->subcategory, $ids  
                                     ) //sprintf
            ); //query
```

If you do not want to use `sprintf()` function, you may use `bindValue()` function of `PDO`:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare('UPDATE :table SET status = 0 
                         WHERE subcategory_id IN ( :ids )'
                       );

$query->bindValue(':table', $wpdb->subcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':ids', $ids, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Still can't updated, it gives error like this : Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() :(

Comment: Still give error : Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object

Comment: @DwikkyMaradhiza I think error occurs because of `$wpdb->subcategory`. Updated the code. try again please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->subcategory 
SET status = 0 
WHERE subcategory_id IN ('1','2','3','4','5')");
```

OR

```
$wpdb->update( $table , $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null );
```

[**Class Reference WPDB**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)